# LESS file wasn't found. Tried -

Tags: css, less

My filesystem tree looks like this:

```
C:.
└───static
    ├───custom_stuff
    │       presets.css
    │       presets.less
    │
    └───index
            index.less
```

So, why `index.less` can't find `presets.less`, and throws me an error:

> '/static/custom_stuff/presets.less' wasn't found. Tried -
>   /static/custom_stuff/presets.less

I'm using VS Code and [this](https://github.com/mrcrowl/vscode-easy-less) extension to compile LESS to CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path will be `../custom_stuff/presets.less`

Comment: thanks so much, I thought about whole month that there is needed only one dot